# Recorded file name is wrong

Tags: java, android, xml

first of all, I'll explain the expected behavior of the App.

### What does the App do?

When I run the App I see this view:

[image]

Now if you hit the "+" button you'll see this Dialog:

[image]

By clicking **Add** this entry will be added to a ListView. I added two items. This looks like this:

[image]

### Expected Result

Now when I touch and hold the mic icon of the list items it should start recording audio through the device microphone and then save this recording with the name of the **bold** entry, that means e.g. the first recording will get the name **A.3gp**, the second one **B.3gp** and so on..

### Actual Result (UPDATE 07.12.2017)

The current state is:

- Every item in the list gets his "own" recording. That means if I touch and hold the microphone icon of the first item in the list, it is doing what it should do. The same goes for all other items on the list.
- When I add the first item **A**, then touch its record icon, a file will be created with the name **A.3gp** (which is correct behavior).
- When I add the second item **B** then do nothing and then add a third item **C** and touch the record icon for **B**, a file will be created with the name **C.3gp** (which is **not** a correct behavior, it should be **B.3gp**).

Now to the fun part.

## Code (UPDATE 07.12.2017)

### 1. The Model

```
public class Word {

    private String mForeignTranslation;
    private String mDefaultTranslation;
    private ImageView mRecordIconImageResourceId;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    public Word(String foreignTranslation, String defaultTranslation, ImageView recordIconImageResourceId) {
        this.mForeignTranslation = foreignTranslation;
        this.mDefaultTranslation = defaultTranslation;
        this.mRecordIconImageResourceId = recordIconImageResourceId;
    }

    public Word(String foreignTranslation, String defaultTranslation) {
        this.mForeignTranslation = foreignTranslation;
        this.mDefaultTranslation = defaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getDefaultTranslation() {
        return mDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public String getForeignTranslation() {
        return mForeignTranslation;
    }

    public ImageView getRecordIconImageResourceId() {
        return mRecordIconImageResourceId;
    }

    public MediaRecorder getMediaRecorder() {
        return mMediaRecorder;
    }

    public void setDefaultTranslation(String mDefaultTranslation) {
        this.mDefaultTranslation = mDefaultTranslation;
    }

    public void setForeignTranslation(String mForeignTranslation) {
        this.mForeignTranslation = mForeignTranslation;
    }

    public void setRecordIconImageResourceId(ImageView recordIconImageResourceId) {
        this.mRecordIconImageResourceId = recordIconImageResourceId;
    }

    public void setMediaRecorder(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder) {
        this.mMediaRecorder = mMediaRecorder;
    }
}
```

### 2. The Adapter

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    private ArrayList<Word> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();


    public WordAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;

        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_word_list_items,parent,false);
        }

        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView foreignWord = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.myForeignWord);
        foreignWord.setText(currentWord.getForeignTranslation());

        TextView defaultWord = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.myDefaultWord);
        defaultWord.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());

        final ImageView recordIconImageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.recordIconImageView);

        wordsArrayList = MyWordsActivity.getWordsArrayList();

        recordIconImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        recordIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mic_red);
                        startAudioRecording();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        recordIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mic_black);
                        stopAudioRecording();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return listItemView;
    }

    private ArrayList<Word> getWordsArrayList() {
        return wordsArrayList;
    }

    private void startAudioRecording() {

        if (wordsArrayList != null) {
            Log.i("ArrayListe", wordsArrayList.toArray().toString());
            getMediaRecorderReady();

            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void stopAudioRecording() {
        try {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void getMediaRecorderReady() {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"speakmylanguage"+"/"+MyWordsActivity.getForeignWord()+".3gp");
    }
}
```

### 3. The Activity

```
public class MyWordsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String defaultWord, foreignWord;
    private static ArrayList<Word> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    WordAdapter wordAdapter;

    // Main Activity Views
    TextView hintTextView;
    ListView myWordsListView;
    FloatingActionButton floatingButtonAddNewWord;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_words);

        // Init Main Activity Views
        hintTextView = findViewById(R.id.hintTextView);
        myWordsListView = findViewById(R.id.myWordsList);
        floatingButtonAddNewWord = findViewById(R.id.fabAddNewWord);

        floatingButtonAddNewWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Dialog addNewWordsDialog = new Dialog(MyWordsActivity.this);
                addNewWordsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_words);
                final EditText addForeignWordEditText = addNewWordsDialog.findViewById(R.id.addForeignWordEditText);
                final EditText addDefaultWordEditText = addNewWordsDialog.findViewById(R.id.addDefaultWordEditText);
                final Button addNewWordButton = addNewWordsDialog.findViewById(R.id.addNewWordButton);
                addNewWordsDialog.show();

                addNewWordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!addDefaultWordEditText.getText().toString().equals("") &&
                                !addForeignWordEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            foreignWord = addForeignWordEditText.getText().toString();
                            defaultWord = addDefaultWordEditText.getText().toString();
                            wordsArrayList.add(new Word(foreignWord, defaultWord));
                            hintTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            addNewWordsDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MyWordsActivity.this, "Please enter two words", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                wordAdapter = new WordAdapter(MyWordsActivity.this, getWordsArrayList());
                myWordsListView.setAdapter(wordAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    public static String getDefaultWord() {
        return defaultWord;
    }

    public static void setDefaultWord(String defaultWord) {
        MyWordsActivity.defaultWord = defaultWord;
    }

    public static String getForeignWord() {
        return foreignWord;
    }

    public static void setForeignWord(String foreignWord) {
        MyWordsActivity.foreignWord = foreignWord;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Word> getWordsArrayList() {
        return wordsArrayList;
    }

}
```

### 4. The Layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myWordsListItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myForeignWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="foreign word" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myDefaultWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:text="default word" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playIconImageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/play_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recordIconImageView"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mic_black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_my_words.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.yousef.mustafa.speakmylanguage.View.MyWordsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/myWordsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".View.MyWordsActivity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddNewWord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hintTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hint"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_add_new_words.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDialogBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addNewWordLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/add_word_title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addForeignWordEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/enter_foreign_word"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addDefaultWordEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/enter_default_word"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNewWordButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/button_add"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should handle the recordingImageView.setOnTouchListener inside your adapter

Comment: hey @mustafa if my code is worked for you. please accept it

Comment: Hey, it helped me a lot, thanks for that. I'm still getting some crashes. Have to find the issue first and fix them..

Comment: @ankitpatidar any chance you could take a look at my changes? Thank you :)

Comment: Ya I will, but what's the problem

Comment: Thanks, please see Actual Results point 3. The main problem is the naming of the recordings in the adapter class. MyWordsActivity.getForeignWord() is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the `startAudioRecording()` method of the Activity, you set the output filename from the `foreignWord` field. The problem is that the `foreignWord` field is set to the most recently added foreign word each time the user submits a word pair in the Add Word dialog. Thus each time the user starts a recording, the name of the output file will be set to the last foreign word added.

Instead of using fields for `recordingImageView`, `foreignWord`, `defaultWord`, `foreignWord`, `audioSavePath`, and `mediaRecorder`, you should make them local variables, and pass them as parameters to your `record()`, `startAudioRecording()`, `stopAudioRecording()` methods with the following steps:

1. Just delete those fields from the beginning of the class so that you see some compilation errors where the fields were used.
2. Where you see an undefined variable on the left side of an assignment, make the variable local (Ctrl+V in Android Studio).
3. Where you see an undefined variable elsewhere, make the variable a parameter of the method (Ctrl+P).

It should work after those changes.

`

Comment: any chance you could take a look at my changes? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Kindly move this snippet :**

```
  recordingImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
 { 
 @Override public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) 
 {   
      switch (motionEvent.getAction()) 
      { 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            { recordingImageView.setImageResource(g startAudioRecording(position); 
                break; 
      } 
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
      { 
           recordingImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mic_black); 
            stopAudioRecording(); 
            break; 
      } 
      } 
      return true; 
 } 
 });
```

**In Adapter , getView(...) Below accessing recordImageView.**

And put startAudioRecording() , stopAudioRecording() in same adapter or all relevant method for recording is to be in Adapter.

*So by this you will get click on in each individual image view. Previously when you are fetching it will only take instance of any one image view.*

**Now update code on "startAudioRecording()" as:**

```
 private void startAudioRecording() 
 { 
      if (checkPermission()) 
      { 
           if (wordsArrayList != null) 
           { 
                audioSavePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + wordsArrayList.get(position) + ".3gp"; 
                getMediaRecorderReady(); 
           } 
      }
 }
```

**Now your   second point, saving its name by any name. Will cover by above code.**

Thanks and happy coding